# Allow authorisation through Facebook or Twitter when a user is navigating my site on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, authorization

Is it possible to allow people to log in to my site on GAE with Facebook/Twitter as an alternative to creating an account on my site?  If they do log in using Twitter, Facebook, etc I would need their email address also so I can implement different levels of authorisation within the site.

I have read a little about Oauth but I cannot find references to how to do it with Facebook and Twitter.  All the docs I have come across talk about Oauth with google accounts only.

How can this be done?

Comment: Look at the Twitter/Facebook docs. Its possible.

Comment: You should know that Twitter uses oauth1, and Facebook uses oauth2, so you need both.  And, most importantly, Twitter does not provide the user's email address, so you cannot match them up with FB or your own auth.

Comment: @gaefan thanks – just to clarify then, without access to an email address how can I uniquely identify someone who logs in, so that I can personalise features when they  log in a second time?

Comment: @gaefan oh and also to clarify once more, Google app engine doesn't have any prebuilt o auth Apis right? I have to implement it myself using URL fetches  or whatever?

Comment: If they oauth via Twitter, you will need to also have them enter their email address to cross-authenticate.  You may need to make your own system.  Maybe someone else knows of some prepackaged.